# Service principal with certificate and VSTS/TFS service endpoint

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

On my current project I work with TFS on-prem and I need to deploy resources in Azure. 
With a service principal in Azure and an ARM service endpoint in TFS, everything works fine.
However now I get the requirement to secure the service principal with a certificate instead of a password. Creating a service principal with a certificate is almost as easy as with a password, but setting up the ARM service endpoint in TFS (also VSTS by the way) is not that easy.

One of the fields I have to fill in for the ARM service endpoint is the "Service Principal Key".
When creating the service principal with a certificate, I don't have that value (which typically is the password used to create the AD application).

Is it possible to create a TFS service endpoint using an Azure service principal based on a certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot create the ARM service endpoint based on a certificate, just as you mentioned we can only provide the "`Service Principal Key`".

However we can create [Azure Classic service endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=vsts#sep-azure-classic) based on a certificate.

> **Management Certificate:**
>
> Required for Certificate based authentication. Copy the value of the
>   management certificate key from your publish settings XML file or the
>   Azure portal.

Comment: As addition to this I'd like to mention that you're limited to v1 of the Azure Resource Group Deployment release task, as v2 only supports the non-classic one.

Comment: Addition two: because only v1 of the Azure Resource Group Deployment release task can be used, it seems ARM templates cannot be deployed using the classic service endpoint? So basically a service endpoint based on certificates cannot be used to deploy ARM templates from TFS?